Android/ Kotlin - geofencingEvent is null
I am following a tutorial on geofencing.
I can place a geofence on the map, and the geofence is clearly added to the database. However when the user goes through the geofence nothing happens.
After checking, I realised that I my log I have the following message: geofencingEvent is null.
I can only image the error to come from the way I handle Intent. But I dont understand what I am missing.
Logs
2024-06-21 16:48:20.574 12783-12783 setPendingIntent        com.example.geofenceapp              D  Creating PendingIntent for geoId: 997924703 with action Intent { cmp=com.example.geofenceapp/.broadcastreceiver.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver }
2024-06-21 16:48:20.574 12783-12783 Flag is                 com.example.geofenceapp              D  flag is 67108864
2024-06-21 16:48:20.576 12783-12783 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.geofenceapp              D  Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10194; state: ENABLED
2024-06-21 16:48:20.579 12783-12783 setPendingIntent        com.example.geofenceapp              D  PendingIntent created: PendingIntent{5377657: android.os.BinderProxy@cf61544}
2024-06-21 16:48:20.609 12783-12783 Geofence                com.example.geofenceapp              D  Successfully added.
2024-06-21 16:48:20.644 12783-12783 geofencingEvent         com.example.geofenceapp              E  geofencingEvent is null
2024-06-21 16:48:20.645 12783-12783 GeofenceBr...stReceiver com.example.geofenceapp              E  GeofencingEvent is null. Intent details: #Intent;launchFlags=0x10;component=com.example.geofenceapp/.broadcastreceiver.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver;end

PendingIntent logic
private fun setPendingIntent(geoId:Int): PendingIntent{
    val intent = Intent(app, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

    Log.d("setPendingIntent", "Creating PendingIntent for geoId: $geoId with action $intent")

  
    val flags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    } else {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    }

    Log.d("Flag is","flag is ${flags}")

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        app,
        geoId,
        intent,
        flags,
    ).also {
        Log.d("setPendingIntent", "PendingIntent created: $it")
    }
}

BroadcastReceiver
class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (context == null || intent == null) {
            Log.e("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "Received null context or intent")
            return
        }

        val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
        Log.e("geofencingEvent", "geofencingEvent is $geofencingEvent")
        if (geofencingEvent == null) {
            Log.e("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "GeofencingEvent is null. Intent details: ${intent.toUri(0)}")
            return
        }

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            val errorMessage = geofencingEvent.errorCode
            Log.e("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "GeofencingEvent error: $errorMessage")
            return
        }

        Log.d("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "Received geofence event: ${geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition}")

        // Handle specific geofence transitions
        when (geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition) {
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER -> {
                Log.d("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "Geofence Enter")
                displayNotification(context, "Geofence ENTER")
            }
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT -> {
                Log.d("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "Geofence Exit")
                displayNotification(context, "Geofence Exit")
            }
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL -> {
                Log.d("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "Geofence Dwell")
                displayNotification(context, "Geofence Dwell")
            }
            else -> {
                Log.d("GeofenceBroadcastReceiver", "Unknown geofence transition: ${geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition}")
                displayNotification(context, "Unknown Geofence Transition")
            }
        }
    }

}

AndroidManifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Geofenceapp"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Geofenceapp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".broadcastreceiver.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>


Found the solution: for this specific case PendingIntent needs to be set as PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE, contrary to general advice. (credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810963/geofence-data-is-empty-on-transition)
